# How to keep tex and installed packages up to date on a Mac with no hassles?

Tags: texlive, mactex

I have MacTeX 2013 basic installed, and I use TexLive to get packages I need for my writing. Recently TexLive told me that the repository is now only for a newer version than what I have installed. I see that MacTex 2014 basic is available, and even though 2013 is working fine for me I get 2014 to make TexLive happy. Now I apparently have two TeX installs. When I delete the 2013 install directory, all the extra packages I had downloaded with TexLive are gone.

I do not want to deal with rebuilding what I previously had just because of a yearly update. I think this is a reasonable expectation, so what am I doing wrong here? Does this problem completely go away if I install the full install instead of basic? Is there a way to make TexLive install packages to a more stable location? I just want a working typesetting system that is keep up to date without a bunch of distracting janitorial work.

Comment: If the extra packages were from CTAN, then a full install should make your problem go away. If they were your own packages, then you'd need to store them in a texmf directory tree under your home directory. There are also [these upgrade instructions](https://www.tug.org/texlive/upgrade.html), and in theory, the Unix upgrade instructions should work on your Mac. I've never tried them, just always done a full install.

Comment: Do the full install.  It's worth it.  As you discovered, doing a new install does *not* overwrite the old distribution.  You get the new one installed alongside the old one.  There's an extra pane in System Preferences that lets you choose which one is the active one.

Comment: @MikeRenfro You don't need to necessarily have extra packages in your home directory. A new installation also leaves the local texmf tree alone (`/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local`). @OP Note that it makes no sense to update TeX Live and keep the old versions of packages you've installed from the previous TeX Live. You want those updated, too. So even if they were not installed in the main tree, you'd need to reinstall them to update. Just install the full scheme, as others have said. Unless you are truly desperate for disk space, nothing else is worth it.

Comment: Also, note that there is no *need* to update TeX Live if it is working fine for you. It will be perfectly 'happy' not being updated.

Comment: @FrustratedUser, I suspect that by "TexLive" you mean "TeX Live Utility", yes? Can you clarify what you meant by "make TexLive happy"? If this was TLU, why were you running it?

Comment: I'm having better luck with the command line than the gui utility recently. tlmgr update